# Does ASP.NET Web API guarantee that the order of elements in an IEnumerable parameter won't be changed?

Tags: collections

I need to call an action method in a ASP.NET Web API, where one of the parameters is an IEnumerable.

From my JavaScript code, I will make a GET request with an array of objects for that parameter.

My question is - does ASP.NET Web API guarantee that the objects in the array won't be reordered? If, for example, I send:

```
[ { name: 'john' }, { name: 'mary' }, { name: 'janice' } ]
```

Can I trust that the order of the objects won't be altered? In practice, they are not, but my functionality strictly depends on this, so I was wondering if there is any guarantee or perhaps a way to enforce it.

Comment: I would never count on that. What if a next version or other tech does not guarantee it? Instead add an ordering index to the items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is part of Linq, not ASP.Net and no there is technically no guarantee of order.  If you need order, using the ordering functions, methods or extensions and return a List instead.